# Que signfifica "linha" (em produtos cosméticos)?

Tags: significado, significado-em-contexto

O que vocês acham que *linha* significa no texto seguinte?

> SOFT CLEANING SHAMPOO – Linha X Y Newway Professional. Shampoo de limpeza suave que age sem agredir os fios, ...

- Tipo do documento: catálogo de produtos cosméticos
- País de origem do texto: Brasil

Eu sinto que significa *coleção*, mas esta definição não aparece no [Dicio](https://www.dicio.com.br/linha/).

Aparece um significado que pode ser adequado: *"orientação, procedimento, técnica."*. Também tem *"trilho"*.

No site do produtor, achei uma seção chamada "Linhas" e aí encontrei "*X Y Blond, X Y Colors, X Y Newway, ..."*.

O que vocês acham?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim, nesse contexto *linha* significa mais ou menos ‘coleção’ ou ‘conjunto de produtos com algo em comum entre eles’. O dicionário que consultaste não é dos mais completos. Se consultares o [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/linha), encontras:

> **linha**
>   […]
>   **14**. Série de produtos: *nova linha de maquiagem*

Ou o [Michaelis:](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/linha/)

> **linha**
>   […]
>   **30** Fig[urativo] Em moda ou cosmética, conjunto de produtos dirigidos a um determinado público ou adequados a uma estação específica, que refletem uma tendência ou orientação: *A linha infantil feminina trouxe este ano muito tecido estampado com flores.*

Comment: Nossa! Que bom! Parece que faltam coisas no dicionário que estou usando mesmo. Achava que era o melhor. Obrigada pela resposta e pelo dicionários!!

Comment: @مريممعاذ , é sempre bom consultar vários dicionários; nenhum dicionário tem absolutamente tudo. Vê [este post no Meta sobre dicionários](https://portuguese.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/304/quais-dicion%C3%A1rios-de-portugu%C3%AAs-brasileiro-s%C3%A3o-confi%C3%A1veis)

Comment: Obrigada. Aprecio seu conselho.